# Is comparing addresses enough for this `operator==`?

Tags: c++, operators

I am creating a custom RTTI system for my event system. Below is the `EventTypeInfo` class. As you can see, it is noncopyable, just as `std::type_info`.

```
class EventTypeInfo
{
  public:
    EventTypeInfo(const EventTypeInfo&) = delete;
    EventTypeInfo& operator=(const EventTypeInfo&) = delete;

    inline bool operator==(const EventTypeInfo& other) const {
        return this == &other;
    }
};
```

The way I create these objects for every event class boils down to this:

```
template<class EventClass>
const EventTypeInfo& event::type::info()
{
    static EventTypeInfo typeinfo;
    return typeinfo;
}
```

Given that (1) these objects are created statically (which means they will last for the entire duration of the application), (2) they are noncopyable, and (3) there's no way to modify an `EventTypeInfo`'s fields without resorting to `const_cast`, is it enough for me to implement `operator==` is terms of `this == &other`, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of a multi-modular application, I think each module might end up with its own copies of static type-info objects. Therefore just comparing an address might be not enough if your events can fly between modules.

As far as I know, [RTTI system in GCC had this sort of problem in past](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#dso), and it caused troubles. Eventually, [GCC developers admitted it and fixed to use string comparison](http://old.nabble.com/C++-v3-PATCH-to-use-strcmp-for-typeinfo-comparison-%28the-plugin-problem,--1-2%29-td24616456.html) in GCC 4.5.

So I would suggest you to do pointer comparison first, and if it fails, then check with a more reliable mechanism.

Comment: (Answering to a now deleted comment about elimination of extra template instantiations) Not sure how MSVC toolchain works with this; GCC relied on weak symbols that `ld` must resolve to a single place. This means that RTTI symbols should be public (which may cause additional troubles, e.g. if developers want tight control over entry points and hide symbols, they may unknowingly hide this RTTI stuff); and as one of the links I give indicates, anyway it was not enough for some complex scenarios.

Comment: I'll pick this as the answer. The problem it describes does not apply to me, but it's something worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that there will ever only be *one* instance of each type, the address compare will be ok.

It is not enough for std::type_info as its uniqueness is not guaranteed by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

#### Semantics of Equal (deep or shallow)

In the general case, I think it's not quite enough.

Consider the case where you have two different instances (addresses), but the same guts/internals.

- Do you want this to return true (what people normally expect, let's say for two strings both with the value "foo" but instantiated at different times)?
- Or false (what your short-cut would return)?

If it's really the latter, then maybe your short-cut would work:  your short-cut is really **one type of a shallow comparison**.

> For instance, if you can guarantee that every event would have a
> different timestamp anyways, which would cause two different instances
> to return false anyhow (and you care about timestamp for comparison
> purposes), using the short-cut would be fine.

Otherwise, do it the normal way (**a deep comparison** or at least **a one-level shallow comparison**).

*Ultimately, it comes down to your interpretation/semantics of what equals means, in this case.*

If you **do** choose to compare addresses, I recommend that you put comments about your implementation so that future readers of your code will understand that you have put thought into your implementation and this is **really** what you intended.

Comment: +1 Good point, but it does not apply in my case. These `EventTypeInfo` objects cannot be modified without resorting to `const_cast`, so you can't normally create a new object and then set its fields to be equal to some other existing object.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us enough of the class to be sure. Without any data members, there's nothing *but* the address to determine if they're equal or not. If there are data members that you haven't included in your example, is it possible to create two instances that contain the same data? Should these instances compare as equal?

Comment: It isn't possible to create two instances with the same data by any normal means (that is to say, you can't _accidentally_ end up with two objects whose fields are the same).